# JQuery Dynamic Object Names

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have this object list

```
var depts = [
  {name:"Sales", phone1:"1.1", phone2:"1.2", phone3:"1.3"},
  {name:"Technical", phone1:"2.1", phone2:"2.2", phone3:"2.3"}
  {name:"Parts", phone1:"3.1", phone2:"3.2", phone3:"3.3"}
]
```

I want to loop through the departments and check if it's a phone number and loop through each phone.

```
$.each (depts, function(i, v) {
    var i
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        phones += v.phone+i + ' ~ '    //This is where I'm having trouble getting.
    };

    console.log(v.name + ' - ' + phones)
});
```

The outcome I'm trying to achieve is this:

```
Sales - 1.1 ~ 1.2 ~ 1.3
Technical - 2.1 ~ 2.2 ~ 2.3
Parts - 3.1 ~ 3.2 ~ 3.3
```

I have tried the following

```
v.window['phone'+i]
window[v+'.phone'+i]
window['v.phone'+i]
```

but I'm getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to do `v.phone + i` which is adding `i` to `v.phone`. Instead, you should do `v[phone + i]`.

Also, I would use `Array.prototype.forEach` for this, although it is your choice:

```
depts.forEach(dept => console.log(`${dept.name} - ${Array.from({length: 3}, (_, i) => dept[`phone${i + 1}`]).join(' ~ ')}`));
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!